# Homorphism and $\varphi(U)$ is normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let be $\varphi:G\to H$ a group homomorphism. Is the following statement true?

Is $U$ a subgroup of $G$ and $\varphi(U)$ a characteristic subgroup of $H$, then is $\varphi(U)$ a normal subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Isn't characteristic subgroup always normal?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a characteristic subgroup $H$ in $G$ is that it is invariant under all automorphisms of $G$. This means $H$ is also invariant under all inner automorphisms $\phi_g$, with $\phi_g(x)=g^{-1}xg$, hence a normal subgroup. So this is independent of the group homomorphism above.